# handlebars won't render HTML image tag? (using NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to render an HTML image tag with handlebars. The HTML does get passed to handlebars properly. (So  does get passed to the webpage, but the image is not rendered.) How do I fix this?

In my .HBS file I have:

```
{{HTMLforImage}} {{image}} {{alt}}
```

and in my .js file I have:

```
  res.render('imageHub', {
  HTMLforImage: "<img src = ",
  image: "\"" + req.body.imageLink + "\"",
  alt: " alt = \"raccoon\">"
});
```

where imageHub is the page handlebars should render the HTML, but instead of a picture being posted I am just getting the HTML being passed onto the webpage. Any ideas on how to fix this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing spaces in between here - {{HTMLforImage}} {{image}} {{alt}}

Comment: I removed the spaces and it's still not working properly.

Comment: from js file just send imageURL and use it in handlebars like
 this -     <img class="someClass" src="{{imgURL}}">

Comment: Why not just send `req.body.imageLink`. image tag and classes aren't dynamic content

Comment: To use HTML in Handlebars you need to surround it with {{{}}}s (reference: https://handlebarsjs.com/, under HTML escaping). So then I'd have to wrap the HTML parts in three curly braces but then put the imgURL part in just regular double braces, and for consistency's stake it would be better to just use Handlebars to render it instead of mixing HTML and Handlebars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{HTMLforImage}}` will escape markup. Try triple brackets: `{{{HTMLforImage}}}`

Comment: {{{HTMLforImage}}}{{{image}}}{{{alt}}} is what ended up working. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use triple braces to escape HTML special characters such as the `<` and `>` characters:

```
{{HTMLforImage}} {{image}} {{alt}}
```

Also you have `<image ...` but it should be `<img ...`

The best practice would be to change your handlebars content to:

```
<img src="{{imageLink}}" alt="{{alt}}" />
```

and pass only the required data like this:

```
res.render('imageHub', {
  imageLink: req.body.imageLink,
  alt: 'raccoon'
})
```